# Show the window shadow when using VCL styles

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

Is there a way to show the window shadow, as per normal Windows 7 forms, when using a VCL style?

I understand the bitmap and settings in the style replaces the form borders, but isn't the shadow some sort of alpha blend / aero thing that is outside the area affected by the style?

Adding CS_DROPSHADOW to the WindowClass.Style seems to have no effect.

Comment: using the CS_DROPSHADOW works for me, Can you show the code which you are using?

Answer (score 5):

Using the CS_DROPSHADOW style works fine

```
type
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
  protected
    procedure CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

procedure TMyForm.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  with Params do
    WindowClass.Style := WindowClass.Style or CS_DROPSHADOW;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: A websearch for CS_DROPSHADOW delphi reveals lots of people suffering from this problem, and it not being related to VCL styles. Seems to me that there is an issue here, albeit hard to repro. Aside: isn't CS_DROPSHADOW defined in Windows.pas?

Comment: There is a difference. CS_DROPSHADOW works fine, OK. But when I put a non-styled, non-drop-shadowed - i.e. a blank form - near the form in the picture, I see it's shadow to be quite a bit more spread. I don't know, but the question maybe about it.

Comment: If you are talking about the shadow drawn by the DWM, this can't be shown because the form style hook uses the `SetWindowRgn` function,  that does not play nicely with dwm and disables the shadow effect effect.

Comment: Has anyone found a different solution for this yet? It doesn't work for us either.

Comment: Is there a way to have shadow that completely surrounds the form? Similar to the standard Microsoft Windows 10/11 app behavior.