# Drawing windows dropshadow on specific control

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe7

I am trying to get the same dropshadow windows uses this one:
[image: dropshadow]

on a treeview control in my form.

[image: editandtree]

On my researching i found out that one can use `CS_DROPSHADOW` ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324571/show-the-window-shadow-when-using-vcl-styles))
 to create this shadow effect on forms.
Is it somehow possible to assign `CS_DROPSHADOW` or something similar to controls as well?

Comment: Is that tree view control going to be a popup window (just like e.g. combo box list) ?

Comment: @TLama I was thinking about implementing it both ways (static and popup).

Comment: From the docs: *Windows created from a class with this style must be top-level windows; they may not be child windows.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Aww, i thought it would be possible without having to use a 2nd form set fsStayOnTop. But i guess that's the only way to do it.